# How to test a pressure sensor on Android?

Tags: android, linux-device-driver

I have seen [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ctsr.android.SensorTest) app, but how can I test the driver of the pressure sensor on Android ?

Comment: Did you check this ? https://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the resolution of your sensor you might see changes depending on the hight of meters above sea level. Try to put it on your desk and the floor, you should see small changes (or go some floors up in your building).

My experience with pressure sensors is, that they are quite inaccurate to measure the hight of the gadget in a small resolution.

To read the values of your sensor, you can also try to read the values from sysfs, if you have shell access.